# Changing an int value into time using casting and setfill

Tags: c++, casting

For a programming assignment, I need to display the time a hypothetical cafe is open. On the weekends the cafe opens an hour and a half later than during the week, but closes at the same time.

The user inputs the opening time, closing time, and how much later it opens on the weekend. The program is supposed to calculate and display the schedule for the cafe. So far my program can do all of this, but I just don't know how to convert a regular integer, such as 845, into the time format, such as 8:45.

My teacher suggesting using casting and setfill. I have tried researching both but I'm just not sure where it applies in the program.

So, how can I convert an integer (e.g. 845) into the time format (e.g. 8:45)?

Comment: You can read about formatting your question by editing and then clicking on the orange ?. Please review and format your code correctly for readability.

Comment: Thank you, I just edited it. Please let me know if you have any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess we can assume that the integer number is always between 0 and 2400, so we're interested in four of it's digits, at most.

One way is to access parts of the integer by division and modulo. Let's take 1245 (12:45) as an example:

1245 / 100 = 12 (always rounded down)

1245 % 100 = 45 (<= [modulo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic) operator)

So by using division and modulo, we can extract the first two numbers (= hours) and second two numbers (= minutes) separately.

The rest is easy:

```
int time = 1245; //your time
int hours = time / 100;
int minutes = time % 100;

//print it
std::cout << hours << ":" << minutes << std::endl;
```

Result: `12:45`